# How to naviagate to C drive from my current Network drive (U:\>) in Command Prompt?

Tags: windows, command-prompt, cd

I'm unable to navigate from `U:\>` in command prompt to `C:\>` using `cd C:` command. U drive is a network drive in my computer.

How to solve this?

Comment: Questions regarding use of your computer operating system (including how to do things from the command prompt) should be asked on [su] instead.

Comment: I can't delete as it has an answer.  Should I flag for moderator intervention?

Comment: I've asked to have it migrated, so it should happen automatically (and take the answers with it as well).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The command is just `C:`, not `cd C:`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change **only the drive**, simply type the drive letter like `C:`

If you want to change **both the drive and current working directory**, use

```
cd /d C:\somefolder
```

That's because cmd maintains a current directory for each drive for backward compatibility with DOS 1.0. See [Why does each drive have its own current directory?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20101011-00/?p=12563)

Of course `cd /d C:` also works, but why do that if you can simply run `C:` (unless you want to go to the root of C: when the CWD in C: is some child folder)? For more information run `cd /?` and read the output

Comment: @KenWhite I fixed the backslash long time ago

Comment: Ok. It was clearly there when I posted my comment, though, or I wouldn't have known about the mistake. :-)